# VB.net and powershell variables

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have a Visual Studio form running with VB.net and I'm collecting info needed to setup an AD user. In the end, this info will need to simply be passed to Powershell with no return info needed. Before that though, I need it to check if a printer code has already been assigned to someone before allowing it to be submitted to another user. I have a simple powershell script written up for it.
(We use the Pager field to store the printer code.)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Page = $args[0]
Get-ADUser -Filter { Pager -like $Page } | FT Name
```

I setup the code I found [HERE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2008/07/26/calling-a-powershell-script-from-your-net-code/), and attempted to modify it to my script but it keeps crashing on

```
Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
```

It gives me: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.ParseException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

If I run his little 6+5 basic example script, it works, but when I try to retrieve info and return a name, it doesn't like it. How can I get it to return the name of the person if it find it? And since it won't run, I'm not even sure if passing the printer code as $args[0] is going to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is expecting a collection of PowerShell objects.  When you pipe the `Get-ADUser` command to `Format-Table`, it effectively strips the object down to a stream of strings.  Try without the `| FT Name`.

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory  #if you're using powershell 3 or later, this may be redundant
 # $Page = $args[0] # don't need to do this
 $results = Get-ADUser -Filter { Pager -like $args[0] }
 Write-Verbose $results
 #Write-Verbose $results.Name  #try this if the above one works
```

---

Update:

`Write-Verbose` may be causing an issue.

Try this:

```
 Get-ADUser -Filter { Pager -like $args[0] }
```

Just that one line as the total PS code.  (Assuming you have PowerShell 3.0 or later, you don't need Import-Module)  That line will return objects of type `TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` (from `Get-ADUser username | Get-Member).

You may also be able to use the .Net object type directly, without PowerShell.  I'm not knowledgeable about .NET beyond what I picked up working with PowerShell.

Accessing AD using .NET, [info from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxk2787(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Same results, and I tried uncommenting the bottom line and seeing if that worked, but it didn't. Is there a better way that the example I'm following for just returning one result to Visual Studio?

Comment: You'd write the PS script to return just the first result.  You'd probably want to verify the count of items in the collection and return error if there is not exactly one result.  Try `Return $results` instead of `Write-Verbose $results`?